# Выделить первую строку TableView JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Необходимо, чтобы при открытии формы с таблицей автоматически выделялась первая строка, и метод который возращает объект выбранной строки

```
Work selectedItem = tvWork.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение своего вопроса:

```
private void FocusFirstRow(){
    tvWork.requestFocus();
    tvWork.getFocusModel().focus(0);
    tvWork.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    Work selectedItem = tvWork.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    workID = selectedItem.getWorkID();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В методе инициализации контроллера пишите:

```
tvWork.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

Метод, запрашивающий выделенный элемент вернет вам первый из таблицы.